# Secure Boot Password not working on Ubuntu (Dell)

Tags: ubuntu, secure-boot

I've been trying to disable Secure Boot on my Dell laptop but it's not working. Every part of the process till the blue screen seems to work fine. But once I enter my password it does not work. It does'nt recognize my password for some reason. I've tried multiple passwords multiple times but it's still not working. Any idea on what the issue might be and how to fix it?

Comment: maybe you are using an incorrect password ... how is this a Linux question?

Comment: TBO I don't understand what password you're entering what's the blue screen and how it related to Linux/Unix.

Comment: hi this probably is the MOK enrollment process. The password you have to enter is the temporary password you defined when setting up the key (keyboard qwerty!!) best is to write down the password as you sometimes are asked for a specific position. what I don't know is if you have to provide your bios password as well (but I believe it is usually done by switching to UEFI setup mode in bios first) a good resource is https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot